# what's wrong with my python re.sub 

Tags: python, regex

this is my code :

```
string ='''
{% emoji 'MONEY_BAG' %}<span style="color:#7F6C41;"><a href="{% mobile_url '/inventory/view_item/?category=weapon&inventory_id=%s' inventory_id %}">{{ item.name }}</a>を入手した!</span></span>


'''
a = r'''
{%\s+mobile_url\s+['"]{1}(/inventory/view_item/\?)[^'"]*['"]{1}\s+([^%}]+)\s+%}
'''

def aa(x):
    print x.group(1)
    print x.group(2)
    return ''

string = re.sub(a, aa, string)
print string
```

and it show :

```
{% emoji 'MONEY_BAG' %}<span style="color:#7F6C41;"><a href="{% mobile_url '/inventory/view_item/?category=weapon&inventory_id=%s' inventory_id %}">{{ item.name }}</a>を入手した!</span></span>
```

i want to print the x.group(1) and the x.group(2)

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your expected output? Also, is it possible that you are trying to [parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/)?

Comment: It's not printing anything because the re never finds a match

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML with regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use regex to extract information from HTML. It's much easier with a HMTL Parser: http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html
Or if you want to crawl a webpage for more information, you might want to use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) which is a truly great web crawler framework.

Comment: BeautifulSoup should be good for lightweight parsing http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2):

Your extra newline characters in `a` are causing the regex to never match

```
a = r'''{%\s+mobile_url\s+['"]{1}(/inventory/view_item/\?)[^'"]*['"]{1}\s+([^%}]+)\s+%}'''
```